# How to align text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to align the name to the left side but it is not working. Always displays in the center suppose I use text-align. So, How to resolve this issue?

```
   Column(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
             children: [
                 Text(
                      "Name",
                      maxLines: 1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      softWrap: false,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(  width: 160,
                        child:Text(
                          "mynameee@gmail.com",
                          maxLines: 3,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          softWrap: true,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),),

                    ],
         ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `column` widget add this line :

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start
```

and remove :

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to `column`:

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

Answer (score 0):

Warp your column with Container and then inside the container enter below line:

```
alignment:Alignment.center
```

Answer (score 0):

add Container for the text and give it  alignment

Like this:

```
Container(
 alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
child:Text('text here')

)
```

And you want display the name and email together use Row

Like this:

```
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
children:[
Text("name:"),
Text("Example@gmail.com"),
]
)
```

And the output well be like this:

```
Name: Example@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Container(
alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
child:Text('text here',textalign:center)

)